# Using Datatables with jQuery and ajax for gathering data gives a strange URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, datatables

So i'm working on a project where I have been able to fetch data out from the database to a JSON endpoint on my server, looking simular to this: `http://some.com/api/herearejson`. I then want to load the data into a table and keep refreshing this table every once in a while.

I'm using Django as by backend and I have come across a javascript library called Datatables (https://datatables.net) and have been setting it up properly. To sum up what I have done is to create a table in the HTML with the top-row-naming of the table. I then use Datatables-framework in javascript to get the data from the JSON file using an ajax-call provided by the framework, to the endpoint of my app.

This is based on the example as shown in the documentation (https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "data/arrays.txt"
    } );
} );
```

This part works like a charm, however after digging into what is really going on I discovered that whenever I do an Ajax-call the following GET-command is sent

```
XHR finished loading: GET "https://some.com/api/herearejson?_=1492196827012".     jquery-1.12.4.js:10254
```

The same message can be shown in the console when loading the example above.

I was wondering if someone can tell me what the last query-like statement at the end of the URL is?

`?_=1492196827012`

To me it looks like some kind of counter that only increases but I don't know where this comes from and why it's there?

It's bothering me not been able to find out what it is, and I'm sceptical of using it since I don't really get where it comes from. Can this have any affect on my application in the long run?

I hope someone can help me figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is anti-cache parameter so browser will always load data from server, not cache.

Comment: Aha! I did not know that, so I guess Datatables has this option as default, and when using something like `function something(){$.ajax({url: url)});` this option is left off? Thank you for your quick answer!

Comment: Yes, this is additional parameter that DataTables use. Many js frameworks do something like that. But $.ajax sends only parameters you pass, so there is no built-in anti-cache generation.